# Is it possible to enable test token endpoint of "standard" MobieFirst Server?

Tags: mobilefirst-server

According to below, test token endpoint is available only in the "development version" of IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation.

[The test token endpoint](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_oauth_test_token_endpoint.html)

We would like to use this endpoint of MobileFirst Server(not development) for test purpose. Is there a property to enable it?

If it is possible, we will secure MobileFirst Server by FW in the test phase. In production, we will disable test endpoint, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this would've been possible, it'd be mentioned. :)
It is not possible. The test token is meant only for testing purposes, in the development server. Once you move to a different environment, you must take care of the token generation.